# django add images to models.py from views.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I create a simple Django authentication app and work fine.
now I want to add a python script where to can do some simple image processing.
my python script for processing work fine and I put in the `views.py`.
my question is the new image created from the script how to can add back to `image` from mymodel ?first must be save temporarily ?
can I do this ?
sorry I am new.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_path(self.user))
```

forms.py

```
@login_required
class CronForm(forms.Form):
    images = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def show_something(request,user_id):
   user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=user_id)
   form = CronForm()
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = CronForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid:
         #  do image processing
         #  do image processing
         # and finaly ta ke new image from the image processing like newim='newim.tif'
      return HttpResponseRedirect(...) 
      errors = form.errors or None
   return render(request, 'path/to/template.html',{
          'form': form,
          'errors': errors,
   })
```

UPDATE :

standalone python processing script :

```
import numpy
inputimage='inputimages.tif'#in some folder
#processing
#processing
#final
newtimage='newtimage.tif'#in some folder
```

I put my script in `views.py` and the `inputimage` I want to take from the form(queryset=MyModel.objects.all) where the user chooses one image where upload before.final I need to add the newimages in `images` from `mymodel` to take path(from upload_to=generate_path(self.user) and store database details.

Comment: the path of new image ?how to save on database ?

Comment: my processing  create a new image

Comment: @Bulva can you help me ?

Comment: yes that I need to store the path in database and id from new image but I use specific folder paths per users `upload_to` in you proposal like this from `django.core.files import File


f = File(open('path_to_file','r'))

m = MyModel.objects.create(one_field='value')

m.file_field = f

m.save()` but in the path can I put this specific path `upload_to=generate_path(self.user))` per user?

that user id that confound me

Comment: must be define first new image with path and after to `MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, image=generate_path(request.user)).` ?

Comment: but in the generate_path I have only the path where I the name o image ?

Comment: can you show an example ?@Bulva thank you to help me

Comment: @Bulva you are wrong your proposal don't work